# Homology group of the Torus using Mayer-Vietoris sequence

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, exact-sequence

I am trying to compute the homology group of the torus $\mathbb T^2$ using Mayer-Vietoris sequence and there is some step I'm struggling with. I know that I should have
$$H_k(\mathbb T^2) = \begin{cases}
\mathbb Z^2 & \text{if } k = 1,\\
\mathbb Z & \text{if } k = 2,\\
\mathbb 0 & \text{else.}
\end{cases}$$
To this end, I consider two disks with the same center embedded in the square $R$ that defines the Torus (just identify the opposite sides two by two), $D_1 \subset D_2 \subset \text{int } R.$ Let us set
$$A = \mathbb T^2 \backslash D_1 \quad \text{and} \quad B = D_2.$$
We have that the wedge product of two circles $S^1 \vee S^1$ is a deformation retract of $\mathbb T^2 \backslash D_1 $ and that $S^1$ is a deformation retract of $A \cap B$. The only part of the Mayer-Vietoris sequence which is non-trivial is given by
$$0 \to H_2(X) \to H_1(A \cap B) \overset{\varphi}{\to} H_1(A) \oplus H_1(B) \overset{\psi}{\to} H_1(X) \to \tilde{H}_0(A\cap B).$$
By what I said above, it can by rewritten as
$$0 \to H_2(\mathbb T^2) \to H_1(S^1) \overset{\varphi}{\to} H_1(S^1 \vee S^1) \oplus H_1(D_1) \overset{\psi}{\to} H_1(\mathbb T^2) \to \tilde{H}_0(S^1),$$
which yields
$$0 \to H_2(\mathbb T^2) \to \mathbb Z \overset{\varphi}{\to} \mathbb Z^2 \oplus 0 \overset{\psi}{\to} H_1(\mathbb T^2) \to 0.$$
Now I do not really see how I could conclude. It seems that if $\varphi$ is the zero map everything works, but is that true ?

Comment: How is $\varphi$ defined? I think it sends the generator $1\in H_1(S^1)$ to $a+b-a-b=0$ in $H_1(A)+H_1(B)$ naturally, where $a$ and $b$ are the corresponding generators. So, it is zero by definition...

Comment: Basically, you just need to show that $\varphi$ is the trivial homomorphism. Since it's induced by the inclusion map, you just need to see what the cycle that generates $H_1(S^1)$ is in $H_1(A)$, and that's $0$. Then by exactness, $\psi$ and $H_2(T^2)\to\Bbb Z$ are isomorphisms.

Comment: $H_0(\mathbb T) = \mathbb Z$. Do you perhaps mean $\tilde H_k$?

Comment: Keep in mind, that homomorphism $\varphi$ has an actual definition: it is the homomorphism induced by the inclusion map $A \cap B \hookrightarrow A$. As hinted in the other comments, you can apply that definition to work out an actual formula for $\varphi$.